# Queuing a method so the view loads faster in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm making a server request to populate a table view using the following code:

The current problem is that the view that this request is made takes a long time to load from the previous view when it's called by the user. How can I queue it so that the view loads then the table loads the data? I've tried moving the  `[self citySearchArrayMethod];` but then the view loads fast but the table is empty.

```
dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);

// execute a task on that queue asynchronously
dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{


    // some code on a main thread (delegates, notifications, UI updates...)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self citySearchArrayMethod]; // populates the city table with city list

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);


// execute a task on that queue asynchronously
dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{

      [self citySearchArrayMethod]; // populates the city table with city list

    // some code on a main thread (delegates, notifications, UI updates...)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

      [self.tableView reloadData]; // load the table with data

    });
});
```